Blazoredmodal.razor.js route "_PAGENAME_content/" instead of "content/"
I have a Blazor Server App, using Blazorize (net core 6).
When my page has this route:
@page "/"
Blazorize tries to retrieve the JS from here (which is correct)
https://localhost:7125/_content/Blazored.Modal/BlazoredModal.razor.js
But when I change my page address to:
@page "/setup"
Then Blazorize tries to retrieve the JS from here (which is incorrect)
https://localhost:7125/setup_content/Blazored.Modal/BlazoredModal.razor.js
Am I doing something wrong?

Ok.
Nothing related to Blazored.
This was the problem. In "_Layout"
    <base href="~/" />

